# NSURLConnection crash when [NSAutoreleasePool drain]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, nsurlconnection, nsautoreleasepool

Hi，I have a crash report as below. I saw many answers about NSURLConnectionInternal crash, but i dont see one which is related to -[NSAutoreleasePool drain]. I really dont know why this happened.Is it really NSURLConnection crashed?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd0000004
raw
0
CoreFoundation
CFRelease + 19
1
CoreFoundation
-[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 160
2
CoreFoundation
-[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 160
3
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 174
4
libobjc.A.dylib
(anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 358
5    CoreFoundation
_CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
6
Foundation
-[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 122
7
Foundation
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 222
8
Foundation
-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 60
9
CFNetwork
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 74
10
CFNetwork
___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 54
11
CFNetwork
___ZNK17CoreSchedulingSet13_performAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 18
12
CoreFoundation
CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
13
CFNetwork
RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 164
14
CFNetwork
MultiplexerSource::perform() + 220
15
CFNetwork
MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
16   CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
22   UIKit
UIApplicationMain + 1136
23
Mahjong-iPad-Double
main.m line 15
main
```

Comment: Something is going wrong when releasing some object, probably an over-release. You might turn on zombies to see if it is caused by an over-release, and if so, of what object.

Comment: it's user's crash log from crashlytics, i cant turn on zombies

Comment: You can't reproduce it? I guess you will have to look closely at your code. It looks like some object that's a member of some array that's autoreleased. The array is possibly autoreleased in a delegate method you provided as a delegate for the connection. Are you using ARC? Maybe you can try Analyze to see if there are any issues?